# Signalr Exception in Browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, signalr

I am trying to create a chat application but after successful build of the web app its catching an exception when i am passing the paramaters for chat.The exception is

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SignalR: Connection must be
>   started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()

The screen shots are attached here
[image]

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831535/signalr-connection-must-be-started-before-data-can-be-sent-call-start-befor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you don't try invoking server-side hub methods until `start` is `done`. Ex:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function(){
     $('#submit').click(function () {
         $.connection.chat.server.addMessage($('#msg').val());
     })
});
```

Notice that the event handler isn't wired up until the connection is established.